# Endianness fun with SHA-2 algorithm

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a SHA-2 implementation, but the result keeps coming back incorrect- I've tested on such things as the empty string. I implemented it in two steps, preprocessing and primary body.

```
template<typename T> struct Output {
    std::array<T, 8> h;
};
template<typename T> struct Input {
    std::array<T, 16> c;
};
template<typename T> Output<T> sha2(Input<T> in) {
    T w[64];
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        w[i] = in.c[i];

    for(int i = 16; i < 64; i++) {
        auto s0 = _rotr(w[i - 15], 7) ^ _rotr(w[i - 15], 18) ^ (w[i - 15] >> 3);

        auto s1 = _rotr(w[i - 2], 17) ^ _rotr(w[i - 2], 19) ^ (w[i - 2] >> 10);
        w[i] = w[i - 16] + s0 + w[i - 7] + s1;        
    }

    static const T k[] = {    
        0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 
        0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 
        0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 
        0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 
        0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 
        0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 
        0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 
        0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 
        0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
    };

    static const T h[] = {
        0x6a09e667,
        0xbb67ae85,
        0x3c6ef372,
        0xa54ff53a,
        0x510e527f,
        0x9b05688c,
        0x1f83d9ab,
        0x5be0cd19
    };

    T loopvars[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        loopvars[i] = h[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        auto&& la = loopvars[0];
        auto&& lb = loopvars[1];
        auto&& lc = loopvars[2];
        auto&& ld = loopvars[3];
        auto&& le = loopvars[4];
        auto&& lf = loopvars[5];
        auto&& lg = loopvars[6];
        auto&& lh = loopvars[7];

        auto s0 = _rotr(la, 2) ^ _rotr(la, 13) ^ _rotr(la, 22);
        auto maj = (la & lb) ^ (la & lc) ^ (lb & lc);
        auto t2 = s0 + maj;

        auto s1 = _rotr(le, 6) ^ _rotr(le, 11) ^ _rotr(le, 25);
        auto ch = (le & lf) ^ ((~le) & lg);
        auto t1 = lh + s1 + ch + k[i] + w[i];

        lh = lg;
        lg = lf;
        lf = le;
        le = ld + t1;
        ld = lc;
        lc = lb;
        lb = la;
        la = t1 + t2;
    }
    Output<T> output;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        output.h[i] = h[i] + loopvars[i];
    }
    return output;
}
Output<unsigned int> SHA2(std::vector<char> bytes) {
    auto bitlen = bytes.size() * 8;
    auto big_endian_bitlen = ::_byteswap_uint64(bitlen);
    if (bitlen > 440)
        throw std::runtime_error("Epic fail!");
    Input<unsigned int> in;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        in.c[i] = 0;
    }
    memcpy(&in.c[0], &bytes.front(), bytes.size());
    in.c[bitlen / 32] |= (1 << (bitlen % 32));
    // all zero by default, so no need to append the extra bits
    in.c[14] = (big_endian_bitlen >> 32);
    in.c[15] = big_endian_bitlen;
    return sha2(in);
}
```

I suspect endianness error. For example, when I listed the input of the primary body, it came back as `1 .. (511x)0`, which I'm pretty sure was correct. But when I tried swapping the values to respect endianness, I still did not get the correct output.

I'm *fairly* sure that the error is in the preprocessing step, as the primary body is endianness-independent, as far as I can tell.

Any suggestions as to where the implementation is incorrect?

Edit: Oh yes, `_byteswap_uint64` is an MSVC intrinsic for endianness conversion of 64bit unsigned integer, and `_rotr` right rotates 32bit unsigned integers. For GCC, you just use macro or define them as functions to the equivalent GCC intrinsics.

Just for reference, the incorrect output is

```
de5c4195
c21e7e70
e6a365c2
77f6bc03
f651e23a
6fb9b88a
1decb688
d6fddf1f
```

whereas the correct output is

```
e3b0c442
98fc1c14
9afbf4c8
996fb924
27ae41e4
649b934c
a495991b
7852b855
```

Comment: Hash algorithms typically work on arrays of bytes. I suspect all that template stuff you have got going with unsigned int types is just getting in the way.  So when you hash an array of anything other than bytes, you can't really expect the same results.  I would suggest getting your code to work on a byte array.  If need be, just cast your int array to a byte array and multiple the length by 4.

Comment: @selbie: The SHA-2 algorithm's primary body takes 16 32bit unsigned words as input. The preprocessing step does indeed take an array of bytes.

Comment: Hmmm... taking a deeper look at your code...

Comment: I see a few potential bugs.  But I have to ask.  What is this line all about?  in.c[i / 32] |= ((bytes[i / 8] >> ((i % 8) & 1)) << (i % 32));  What is it intending to accomplish?

Comment: @selbie: Just unpacking the input bytes into the array. It's actually mostly legacy from another version- I could just replace it with `memcpy` I guess.

Comment: To compile on gcc: `#define _byteswap_uint64 __builtin_bswap64` / `#define _rotr(x,k) (((x)>>(k)) | ((x)<<(32-(k))))`

Comment: Related, you can find source for both Intel SHA intrinsics and ARMv8 SHA intrinsics at [Noloader GitHub | SHA-Intrinsics](http://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics). They are C source files, and provide the compress function for SHA-1, SHA-224 and SHA-256. The intrinsic based implementations increase throughput approximately 3x to 4x for SHA-1, and approximately 6x to 12x for SHA-224 and SHA-256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some extracts from a working implementation would be helpful -- especially since it emphasizes following the FIPS description quite closely rather than any mundane considerations like efficiency. :-) Probably the biggest deviation is using temp[0]...temp[7] for what the FIPS calls `a`, `b`, ...`h` and temp[8] and temp[9] for T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub>.

```
namespace {
    uint32_t word(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        a &= 0xff;
        b &= 0xff;
        c &= 0xff;
        d &= 0xff;
        int val =  a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
        return val;
    }

    uint32_t ROTR(uint32_t number, unsigned bits) { 
        return (number >> bits) | (number << (32-bits));
    }

    uint32_t f1(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) { 
        return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);
    }
    uint32_t f2(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) { 
        return (x & y) ^ (x&z) ^ (y&z);
    }
    uint32_t f3(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 2) ^ ROTR(x, 13) ^ ROTR(x, 22);  
    }
    uint32_t f4(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 6) ^ ROTR(x, 11) ^ ROTR(x, 25);
    }
    uint32_t f5(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 7) ^ ROTR(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3);
    }
    uint32_t f6(uint32_t x) { 
        return ROTR(x, 17) ^ ROTR(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10);
    }

    uint32_t add(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

sha256::sha256() : H(hash_size), W(64), temp(10) { 
    static const uint32_t H0[hash_size] = {
        0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 
        0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19
    };

    std::copy(H0, H0+hash_size, H.begin());
}

void sha256::hash_block(std::vector<uint32_t> const &block) {
    static const uint32_t K[] = {
        0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
        0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5, 
        0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
        0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
        0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
        0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
        0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
        0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
        0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
        0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
        0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
        0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070, 
        0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
        0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
        0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
        0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
    };

    assert(block.size() == 16);

    std::copy(block.begin(), block.end(), W.begin());
    for (int t=16; t<64; ++t) 
        W[t] = f6(W[t-2]) + W[t-7] + f5(W[t-15]) + W[t-16];
    std::copy(H.begin(), H.end(), temp.begin());

    for (int t=0; t<64; ++t) {
        temp[8] = temp[7]+f4(temp[4]) + f1(temp[4],temp[5],temp[6])+K[t]+W[t];
        temp[9] = f3(temp[0]) + f2(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
        temp[7] = temp[6];
        temp[6] = temp[5];
        temp[5] = temp[4];
        temp[4] = temp[3] + temp[8];
        temp[3] = temp[2];
        temp[2] = temp[1];
        temp[1] = temp[0];
        temp[0] = temp[8] + temp[9];
    }
    std::transform(H.begin(), H.end(), temp.begin(), H.begin(), add);
}
```

I'd tend to agree with your guess though: I'd suspect the padding routine. At least in my experience, the padding is harder to get correct than the hash routine itself (partly because it isn't described as carefully).

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes. I don't have a BE machine to test with, but I *believe* it should work correctly there as well.

Comment: Uh, not to be a complaining kind of guy, but it would be nice to see *all* the source for that impl, as the missing bit is the padding routine, which is the bit which I'm fairly sure is incorrect.

Comment: @DeadMG: I've put it up at: http://ideone.com/E2g9Y, with the header and source merged, but comments to mark the boundary (and a `#define TEST` at top so it builds with code to hash the test vectors from the FIPS pub).

Answer (score 0):

```
in.c[i / 32] |= ((bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8))) << (i % 32));
```

bytes is an array of "char".  char is typically signed.  (That's the default on Visual Studio, and I'm guessing gcc).  So when you right shift "bytes[i/8]", it's going to carry the sign extension with it.  That is if bytes[0] is 0xf0.  Then (bytes[0] >> 4) will be 0xff, not 0x0f.

Comment: I should point out that I believe the standard for right-shift is "undefined" for signed types. But most compilers default to a signed shift.  Might be standard in latest C and C++ specs.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when I replace with `memcpy`, the problem is still true. Notably, I tried the empty string as input because it's all zeroes except for a single 1, which quite limits the places where things can be going wrong.